# Migrating Highstock 1.3.9 to Highstock 2.0.4

Tags: jquery, highcharts

```
Is there any issues if i migrate Highstock 1.3.9 to Highstock 2.0.4?
```

Currently i am using jQuery 1.7.2.

Comment: you're better off trying it and go from there.

Comment: Please update, and let us know if you come across any issues.

Comment: @ Sebastian Bochan, sure